# About the issue with Facebook's message field

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver

I am currently encountering a problem using Selenium to operate Facebook. The message box stays in a "loading" state when trying to open it with Selenium, but it works correctly when not using Selenium.

[image]

The screen on the right is operated by using Python to control Selenium, while the screen on the left is the normal display of Chrome. Both are operated at the same time. The screen on the left can be opened normally, but the one on the right is always in a loading state (even after waiting for an hour, it is still loading).

*Only the message box has a problem, and other Facebook interface and features are working normally.

The following methods have been tried:

Reinstalling user data in Chrome.
Completely uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome.
Testing other accounts on the same computer, which resulted in the same problem.
Upgrading Selenium to the latest version.
Chrome has no other extensions, and the driver versions are all up to date.
Google Analytics is set up, and all other features except the message box are working correctly.
Cross-testing has been conducted, and it has been determined that the problem is not caused by the program or by anti-crawling mechanisms.

On the same computer, without using Python, the message box can be opened normally under the same account with Chrome (this eliminates the possibility of the Facebook account being blocked or anti-crawling issues).
On a different computer, the same Python program can be used normally (this eliminates the possibility of the Python code being incorrect).

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to interact with the website programmatically. Using their API is the only allowed way.

Comment: (1) Did you trying using the undetected chromedriver? (2) Did you trying to access the chats via https://www.facebook.com/messages?